# What is the return value of Currentmember.Level? (MDX)

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

is the return value of Currentmember.level an integer or something else?
I get only null values if I try to show me the value.

Here are two pictures about my hierarchy: https://abload.de/img/screenshot_zeite1kns.png
https://abload.de/img/screenshot_zeit_attrio5j17.png

Answer (score 1):

How your MDX query looks like:

Something like this should return level names:

```
with member measures.currentmemberlevel as [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Level.Name
select measures.currentmemberlevel on 0,
[Date].[Calendar].members on 1
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, if I write [Time].[Calendar].CurrentMember i get the month-value. With [Time].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Level, Null Values. Is the .Level an Integer or what is it?

Comment: @Detlef7able it’s a Level object with properties like Name and Members

Answer (score 0):

If you want level as an integer try
... .currentmember.level_number

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).